# How to categorize in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have to categorize app into two high  and medium  what I 
want to set app which is on high risk in high column and medium risk in medium column how can I do that,here is code that I am trying to implement but not success

here is code:-

```
public void _fillRowData(int position, View rootView) {
    if (position == _appHeaderIndex || position == _systemMenacesHeaderIndex) {
        ResultsAdapterHeaderItem obj = (ResultsAdapterHeaderItem) getItem(position);
        ResultsAdapterHeaderItem header = (ResultsAdapterHeaderItem) obj;
        TextView headerText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Titlelabel);
        headerText.setText(header.getDescription());
    } else if (_systemMenacesHeaderIndex == -1 || position < _systemMenacesHeaderIndex) //We are receiving something that is not a header and no system menaces
    {
        final ResultsAdapterProblemItem ri = (ResultsAdapterProblemItem) getItem(position);
        final AppProblem ap = ri.getAppProblem();

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Titlelabel);
        TextView riskText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qualityApp);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        if (ap.isDangerous()) {
            riskText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.HighRiskColor));
            riskText.setText(R.string.high_risk);
        } else {
            riskText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.MediumRiskColor));
            riskText.setText(R.string.medium_risk);
        }

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemParent);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (_onItemChangedStateListener != null)
                    _onItemChangedStateListener.onItemSelected(ap);
            }
        });
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (_onItemChangedStateListener != null)
                    _onItemChangedStateListener.onItemSelected(ap);
            }
        });


        textView.setText(StaticTools.getAppNameFromPackage(getContext(), ap.getPackageName()));
        imageView.setImageDrawable(StaticTools.getIconFromPackage(ap.getPackageName(), getContext()));
    } else {
        final ResultsAdapterProblemItem ri = (ResultsAdapterProblemItem) getItem(position);
        final SystemProblem sp = ri.getSystemProblem();

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Titlelabel);
        TextView riskText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qualityApp);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logo);

        if (sp.isDangerous()) {
            riskText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.HighRiskColor));
            riskText.setText(R.string.high_risk);
        } else {
            riskText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.MediumRiskColor));
            riskText.setText(R.string.medium_risk);
        }

        RelativeLayout linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemParent);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (_onItemChangedStateListener != null)
                    _onItemChangedStateListener.onItemSelected(sp);
            }
        });
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (_onItemChangedStateListener != null)
                    _onItemChangedStateListener.onItemSelected(sp);
            }
        });

        textView.setText(sp.getTitle(getContext()));
        imageView.setImageDrawable(sp.getIcon(getContext()));
    }
}
```

Comment: not clear what you want to do. Do you want to sont your list in some specific order?

Comment: yes that what want I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sort your collection before setting it to adapter

```
List<ResultsAdapterProblemItem> yourList = ...;
        Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<ResultsAdapterProblemItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ResultsAdapterProblemItem lhs, ResultsAdapterProblemItem rhs) {
                if(lhs.getAppProblem().isDangerous()) {
                    if(rhs.getAppProblem().isDangerous()) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else if(rhs.getAppProblem().isDangerous()){
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

After this the dangerous items will be at the top of the list, and non-dangerous - at the bottom. Now you can set this list as a source of the adapter